# es6/Redux help: need help spreading state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I am still confused with how to spread state properly.
I have an object that holds a collection of users:

```
let users={
    user1:{
        id: 'user1',
        name: 'name',
        favorites:[
            'Shrimp & Snap Pea Stir-Fry',
        ],
        lists:{
            list1:[
                'Shrimp & Snap Pea Stir-Fry'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I've seen examples and so far I can spread state
for id, name and favorites.  but where I am confused is
Lists:  lists is a collection of arrays. I don't know how to spread up to  that depth in my code.

In my reducer for Users I have an action type "TOGGLE_LIST_ITEM"
and Im currently trying to figure out how to spread my state so I can modify it . here is what I have so far

code for the TOGGLE_LIST_ITEM case :

```
        case TOGGLE_LIST_ITEM:

        const authedUser = action.listItem.authedUser
        const dishTitle = action.listItem.dishTitle
        const list = action.listItem.list

        return{
            ...state,
            [authedUser]:{
                ...state[authedUser],
                    lists: /*here I have to goto the correct list inside of lists*/
            }
        }
```

thank you for your help.

edit:  im closer with this but not quite

```
    return{
            ...state,
            [authedUser]:{
                ...state[authedUser],
                lists:
                    state[authedUser].lists[list].concat([dishTitle])
            }
            
        }
```

as of now it replaces the entire list1 array with a dish title. as oppose to writing it into list1 array.

Comment: isn't it easier if u just use something like https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#simplifying-immutable-updates-with-redux-toolkit? otherwise I'd filter the list before returning the object and include the item you want to edit

Comment: What value/property in `action.listItem.list` correlates to the lists arrays in state so you update the correct one? Is it replacing the existing entry or is it updating the contents of the existing array?

Comment: @DrewReese action.listItem.list is the key of the list I want to access.  maybe i should change it to action.listItem.key ...   basically I want to add or delete an item inside a particular List which is inside Lists.

Comment: Ah, so is the idea to add or remove (i.e. toggle) `action.listItem.dishTitle` from `state[authedUser].lists` using `action.listItem.list` as the key to grab the correct list array?

Comment: @DrewReese correct.  the non immutable way would look like this: user1.lists[list1].concat([dishTitle])

Comment: @DrewReese I posted an edit to my OP.  i'm really close to solving my issue. I hope its helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To selectively toggle a value into and out of an array you'll need to first search for it in the array. If present then filter it out, if not then append it to array. You have to continue spreading each nested level of state you access and mutate.

```
case TOGGLE_LIST_ITEM:
  const authedUser = action.listItem.authedUser;
  const dishTitle = action.listItem.dishTitle;
  const listKey = action.listItem.list;

  const list = state[authedUser].lists[listKey];

  const dishItemFound = list.includes(dishTitle);

  let newList;
  if (dishItemFound) {
    // dishItem was found, filter list
    newList = list.filter(title => title !== dishTitle);
  } else {
    // dishItem was not found, append to list
    newList = [...list, dishTitle];
  }

  return {
    ...state,
    [authedUser]:{
      ...state[authedUser],
        lists: {
          ...state[authedUser].lists,
          [listKey]: newList,
        },
    }
  }
```

Comment: Awesome. This was very elegantly written too. big thanks !